# How to display text when hovering over an Image

Tags: macos, image, swiftui

My intent is to display the location of the cursor in Image coordinates when the cursor is over the image.  As an initial step I can print the location but I need to display it to the user.  I've found some possible solutions but none that do what I need.

The code below works except that I need to display the position.  How do I display the position near the cursor?

```
struct ImageView: View {
var body: some View {
    Image("testImage") // placeholder
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 640, height: 480)
        .onHover { hover in
            if hover {
                NSCursor.crosshair.push()
            } else {
                NSCursor.pop()
            }
        }
        .onContinuousHover { phase in // (col, row)
             switch phase {
             case .active(let location):
                 print("---> location: \(location)") // WORKS
             case .ended:
                 break
             }
         }
}
```

}

Comment: Set a `@State` variable with the position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the location like this:

```
struct ImageView: View {
    
    @State var location: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Current location: \(location.x), \(location.y)")
            
            Image("testImage") // placeholder
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 640, height: 480)
                .onHover { hover in
                    if hover {
                        NSCursor.crosshair.push()
                    } else {
                        NSCursor.pop()
                    }
                }
                .onContinuousHover { phase in // (col, row)
                    switch phase {
                    case .active(let location):
                        NSCursor.crosshair.push()
                        self.location = location
                    case .ended:
                        break
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The location prints in Text but the NSCursor no longer changes to crosshair.

Comment: you can put `NSCursor.crosshair.push()` in `case .active`. I edited the code