# What is the way to extract the value of an Image pixel given that a GCPoint value is available?

Tags: macos, swiftui, core-graphics

I have an Image View which displays an image and the CGPoint when the cursor is over the image.  I am able to get and display the cursor position in pixels but cannot figure out how to get the value of the pixel rgb.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ImageView: View {
    
    @State var location: CGPoint = .zero
    @State var didHover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Os três")
                .font(.system(size: 16))
            
            Image("Burros_1") // placeholder
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                .frame(width: 640, height: 480)
                .border(.green)
                .onHover { hover in
                    if hover {
                        NSCursor.crosshair.push()
                    } else {
                        NSCursor.pop()
                    }
                }
                .onContinuousHover { phase in // (col, row)
                    switch phase {
                    case .active(let location):
                        NSCursor.crosshair.push()
                        self.location = location // WORKS
                        self.didHover = true
                    case .ended:
                        self.didHover = false
                        break
                    }
                }
            
            // GOAT add DN
            let rowString = String(format: "%03d", Int(round(location.x)))
            let colString = String(format: "%03d", Int(round(location.y)))
            
            if didHover {  // Missing pixel value GOAT
                Text("(r, c, DN) \(rowString), \(colString), ??")
                    .monospaced()
            }
            else {  // this conserves a line for the Text
                Text(" ")
            }
        } // VStack
    } //
}
```

I've searched on-line, including stack overflow, extensively but most results are for iOS, not macOS, and don't really address my problem or won't compile. I've also 'jumped' to definitions to try to spot a method but no luck.

Comment: Could you tell us which SwiftUI topic for iOS is not applicable to your case and why?

Comment: @ElTomato Well they didn't compile.  Of course I'm new to Swift and SwiftUI and they showed their examples for an iPhone so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach using `NSBitmapImageRep`, to get the pixel rgb.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ImageView()
    }
}

struct ImageView: View {
    let nsimg = NSImage(named: "mycat")!
    @State private var location: CGPoint = .zero
    @State private var pixelColor: NSColor?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("location: \(location.debugDescription)")
            Text("color: \(pixelColor?.debugDescription ?? "no color")")
            
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Image(nsImage: nsimg)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 640, height: 480)
                    .onContinuousHover { phase in
                        switch phase {
                        case .active(let location):
                            NSCursor.crosshair.push()
                            self.location = location
                            
                            // todo convert coords using GeometryReader
                            
                            pixelColor = nsimg.colorAt(location)
                        case .ended:
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    .border(.green)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            pixelColor = nsimg.colorAt(CGPoint(x: 20, y: 60)) // for testing
            print("---> pixelColor: \(pixelColor)")
        }
    }
    
}

extension NSImage {
    func colorAt(_ pos: CGPoint) -> NSColor? {
        let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: self.tiffRepresentation!)
        return imageRep?.colorAt(x: Int(pos.x), y: Int(pos.y))
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, this retrieves the RGBA data but it results in the cursor in motion being crosshairs but poping when not, and being jerky when moving across the image.  Also the text that I wanted to follow, that is, be below the image is right in the middle of it.  I've not used GeometryReader before.

Comment: I was answering the question `...how to get the value of the pixel rgb.`, and as you say,
this does it, given the appropriate coordinates transform. The `Text` for testing are displayed at the top 
of the view, not in the middle, to make them appear below the Image, move them after the `GeometryReader`, as simple as that.

To address the other questions about the cursor see the answer to your previous post, here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78048973/how-to-display-text-when-hovering-over-an-image   or it could even be another SwiftUI bug.

Comment: If I cannot solve the placement pronlem I'll post a new question.  I'm marking this solved.

Comment: thank you. Re your placement of the text, my code does not place the text in the middle of the image, and using the code that you show does not either, the text is displayed below the image.

Comment: Not imbedding Image in GeometryReader solved the problem!